# Sharing variables across recursion calls (lists, sets)

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I'm starting to solve some questions on recursion, where I noticed the need of having a shared variable (such as a set/list) to append (or add in case of a set) results to and return. I searched online and found some solutions, which seem to work for me in some cases and not in others - I tried global variables, lists defined outside the recursive functions and so on.

I'm unable to understand why it works in certain cases and doesn't work in others (maybe I'm missing how the recursion calls are working?)

```
# Shared list/set across multiple calls: Works
# Task: Print from n in descending order
s = [] # list defined outside the recursive function
def rec(n):
    if n == 0:
        return s
    else:
        s.append(n)
        rec(n-1)
        return s

print(rec(5))
# prints: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], as expected.
```

This also works if I pass a shared variable as a part of the function call:

```
def rec(n, s=[]):
    if n == 0:
        return s
    else:
        s.append(n)
        rec(n-1, s)
        return s
    
print(rec(5))
# prints: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], as expected.
```

Next, similarly, I tried this on the next task:

```
# Task: Print permutations of [1, 2, 3]: Doesn't work!
lst = []
def permuteArr(arr, idx=0):
    if idx == len(arr):
        print(arr)
        lst.append(arr)
    
    for i in range(idx, len(arr)):
        arr[i], arr[idx] = arr[idx], arr[i]
        permuteArr(arr, idx+1)
        arr[i], arr[idx] = arr[idx], arr[i]

permuteArr([1, 2, 3])
print(lst) # prints: 
# [1, 2, 3]
# [1, 3, 2]
# [2, 1, 3]
# [2, 3, 1]
# [3, 2, 1]
# [3, 1, 2]
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
# why is the list different from the printed arr values 
# when I have lst defined outside the function?
# Also doesn't work when I pass lst as an argument like earlier.
```

Similarly, I'm trying to solve the leetcode problem of number of Islands: https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/queue-stack/231/practical-application-queue/1374/ recursively with DFS.
I used this video to understand how to solve this recursively: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZixJexAaOAk and the lady here, she marks the visited nodes with `0` (for water). If I try to maintain a visited set here like so:

```
from collections import deque
def numIslands(grid):
    """
    :type grid: List[List[str]]
    :rtype: int
    """
    # Approach #4: Using recursive DFS, outside visited.
    # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZixJexAaOAk
    def dfs(grid, r, c):
        # global visited - doesn't work. NameError
        # Passing visited as a variable in this call also fails
        if r<0 or r>=ROWS or c<0 or c>=COLUMNS or (r, c) in visited:
            return
            # Mark this node as water now (visited)
            # Since this is marked as 0 in-place,
            # the outer function won't consider this in the next loop
        if grid[r][c] == "1":
            visited.add((r, c)) # visited set instead of grid[r][c] = 0
            dfs(grid, r+1, c)
            dfs(grid, r, c+1)
            dfs(grid, r-1, c)
            dfs(grid, r, c-1)
        

    output = 0
    ROWS, COLUMNS = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    visited = set()

    for r in range(ROWS):
        for c in range(COLUMNS):
            if grid[r][c] == "1":
                # visit all the neighbours of this "1" and come back
                dfs(grid, r, c)
                output+=1

    return output


numIslands([
  ["1","1","1","1","0"],
  ["1","1","0","1","0"],
  ["1","1","0","0","0"],
  ["0","0","0","0","0"]
])
```

I receive a maximum recursion depth reached, because from what I understand, its not finding the visited nodes and just recursing through them again and again. I tried passing `visited` as a part of the dfs function call and creating visited as a global variable (received `NameError` as function wasn't able to find visited), all of which don't work.

How to maintain shared variables correctly across recursion calls in these instances? Why does it work for some, but not for the other cases I mentioned?

Comment: In your `permuteArr` example, `arr` is always the same reference to a single list in memory. So when you change it in one place all the references are changed. You print its current value, but later change it. Generally speaking, you should avoid side effects if you can. Your first two examples can be done without shared state. (ie. : `def rec(n): return [] if n <= 0 else [n] + rec(n-1)`)

Comment: I understand that sets and lists refer to the same locations in memory and thats why sharing them typically across multiple calls works when I have list defined outside the function. Can you explain a bit more on what you mean by: `You print its current value, but later change it.` -- when I'm appending to the list, isn't the same behaviour being followed by the `rec` function. Whats different between the two? @3874623

Comment: And thats a nice way to append to the lists, thanks!

Comment: The argument `arr` is a reference to a list. When you do `lst.append(arr)` you append another reference of the **same list** (`arr`) to `lst`. Then later you change `arr`, which all these references are pointing to. This is one of the reasons functional programming avoids mutating the input to functions — that's a side effect and it makes debugging difficult. This problem has nothing to do with the shared `lst` array — that's doing what you expect, it's just that it holds a bunch of references to a single piece of memory that you are mutating as you go.

Comment: Another way that may help you understand what is going on: run `permuteArr()` like you are and look at `lst`. Now modify the first element of the first sublist: `lst[0][0] = 999`. Now print it again. All the lists changed, right? Why? Because there is only one list.

Comment: Why not just access the common information with a getter and a setter method?

Comment: My bad - that was meant to be an `or` in the last condition! I have corrected it. @rici

Comment: @Mark - I do understand that a through all the recursive calls, the list is shared and other calls simply carry a reference to the list. >> "it holds a bunch of references .. you are mutating as you go" - I would expect that if single piece of memory was mutating, it'd produce one element in the list getting updated, or perhaps uneven number of list elements. How does it account for exactly 6 elements in the list with the input added to it? `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`. So, the recursive calls are appending to the list at different memory cells.

Comment: @Mark - I got it. I was thinking about `lst`, and not about `arr`. Both are arrays. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid persistent state whenever possible. And you should particularly avoid global persistent state. If your recursive function uses a global container, you will only be able to call it once; after that, the global container is contaminated with data from the first call.

Note that using a container as a default argument is effectively the same as using a global variable, with one additional fatal flaw: unlike real global variables, which could in theory be reset, there is no convenient way to reset a default argument specification. When you write:

```py
def func(s=[]):
    …
```

the function definition is executed once. It's not executed again unless you redefine the function. And when the definition is executed --**not** ehen the function is called-- the default value is computed and stored in the function's prototype. In the above example, the default value is a list, and so it will always be the same list. That's very rarely what you want.

I suppose you didn't notice that issue with the first function because you only tried running the function once. Once is not enough testing, ever. (Unless you're building a Doomsday device, in which case once is too many. I honestly never thought Dr. Strangelove would return to relevancy.)

Python offers a couple of ways to overcome this problem, although the best solution is almost always to avoid depending on mutable state. One possibility is to pass the mutable value as an argument to the recursive function, which is really only feasible if you write a wrapper which creates the mutable container and calls the recursive function with it:

```py
def rec_helper(n, s):
    if n:
        s.append(n)
        return rec_helper(n-1, s)
    else:
        return s

def rec(n):
    return rec_helper(s, [])
```

But a cleaner solution is often to make the helper function a nested function and use closures for the mutable state:

```py
def rec(n):
    s= []
    def helper(n):
        if n:
            s.append(n)
            return helper(n-1)
        else:
            return s

    return helper(n)
```

Far and away the cleanest, as mentioned above, is to avoid mutable state:

```py
def rec(n):
    def helper(n, s):
        if n:
            return helper(n-1, s + [n])
        else:
            return s
    return helper(n, [])
```

Comment: `One possibility is to pass the mutable value as an argument to the recursive function` - can you give the same example for `permuteArr` which I have listed above? Because when I'm trying something similar for it, it doesn't work very well. The gist of my question is to understand why this works for one case and doesn't work for the other. But I do understand from your answer as to the "better ways of sharing a list" across recursive calls.

Comment: @user2816215: the problem with `permuteArr`, as noted by Mark, is that you are always appending the same  array to `lst`. You need to append a *copy* of the array: `lst.append(arr[:])`. That's a different mutable-state gotcha, and again the clearest solution simply avoids shared state.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand. Trying it out

Comment: Just to reiterate - this problem doesn't affect the rec function because `n` is being appended to the list and its not affected by the same issues as a `arr` (the same memory location being mutated across calls). We aren't updating at n's memory location. In `arr`, the same array was being swapped and hence `arr` was always returned to its original state after the recursive call (in the last swap), changing all the appended variables in the list because they were referring to the same memory location. Can you confirm this?  @rici

Comment: @user2816215: yes, that's basically it. Python's numbers are first-class objects, so they can be shared. But they cannot be mutated. If you could mutate a number, you'd see the same phenomenon (which is why you can't). `n += 1` sets `n` to a new number object. `arr = arr + [n]` sets `arr` to a new array object. But `arr.append(n)` does not. These are things you need to understand about Python, whether or not you want to write recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to share variables in recursion calls, much like using global variables, but slightly different - by making use of `nonlocal` keyword.

```
# Trying to use a counter across recursion calls
def factorial(x):
    counter = 0 
    def helper(x):
        if x == 0:
            return 1
        counter+=1 # UnboundLocalError
        return x*helper(x-1)
    
    print(counter)
    res = helper(x)
    print(counter)
    return res
```

and with `nonlocal` keyword:

```
def factorial(x):
    counter = 0 
    def helper(x):
        nonlocal counter
        if x == 0:
            return 1
        counter+=1
        return x*helper(x-1)
    
    print(counter)
    res = helper(x)
    print(counter)
    return res
```

Similarly, using `counter = [0]` and then incrementing `counter[0]+1` also works because lists are maintained as reference across multiple calls and a new copy isn't created. So the same memory location is used for incrementing across all recursive calls.

Just fyi - for anyone looking out for this.